# Gradle: cache task which processes a file in-place

Tags: gradle

I have a bit of a specialized case. I'm writing a Gradle plugin which processes a file in-place. It's a `package.json` file; the plugin fills in missing keys in the JSON file. Therefore, all follow-up runs of the plugin task "do nothing": after the keys have been filled in, the JSON file is stable and doesn't need to change. The processing takes quite some time, so the plugin would definitely benefit from build cache.

The plugin both reads and writes to the same file, therefore the file should be marked both with `@InputFile` and `@OutputFile` annotation. However, that does not seem to be possible with Gradle. I tried to introduce two separate properties, one annotated with `@InputFile` and the other with `@OutputFile` but the caching is suffering from the "overlapping outputs" issue and the caching doesn't work.

Is there a Gradle property annotation which would combine `@InputFile` and `@OutputFile`, or which would mark the file as edited in-place?

There's a question on Gradle Forums in this regard, but it's unclear how to use the `@Incremental` annotation (and whether it's the right one): https://discuss.gradle.org/t/use-incremental-with-files-being-both-input-and-output/35984

Comment: You say the file doesn't change, but the plugin reads and writes to the same file? Why does it read and write if nothing changes? As you have probably surmised, Gradle is very much designed around having separate inputs and outputs. Is there a reason you cannot have separate output copies of the file? That would be the natural solution. Or indeed another file object to record the output

Comment: The plugin modifies the file during the first run, but all subsequent runs leave the file unmodified. The package.json is required to be located in project root since it’s a Vaadin project and Vaadin runs NPM tool chain which expects package.json in root. This kind of functionality is similar to code formatting plugins, or new line character modification plugins which also work in-place; I wonder how those kinds of plugins mark their inputs/outputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### The intended approach

The cleanest way of chaining tasks which access files in Gradle is for each changed file to be placed in a new location, and for subsequent tasks to access those files from that new location. However, sometimes that isn't possible due to the configuration of those subsequent tasks.

##### The work-around

The work-around (as suggested in your forum link) is to:

1. Have the task which modifies the unmovable files place the modified files in a new directory (in the normal fashion),
2. Run a subsequent task action which "silently" copies those files back and overwrites the original files, and
3. Set your modification task as a finalizer task for the original task which created the unmovable files so that it runs when tasks which depend on that original task are invoked.

Then we achieve the objective of modifying the file in-place, with Gradle build caching working as normal. All the original tasks use their original files as reference points for cache invalidation, plus your modification task has its own new file location for the same.

##### An example

###### Original setup

To give an example, suppose we have an original `build.gradle.kts` as follows (all code in Kotlin):

```
tasks {
    val createOriginalFileTask = register<OriginalTask>("createOriginalFile") {
        outputFile.set(layout.buildDirectory.file("hello.txt"))
    }
    register("originalDependant") {
        dependsOn(createOriginalFileTask)
        doLast {
            println("Found contents: ${createOriginalFileTask.get().outputFile.get().asFile.readText()}")
        }
    }
}
```

And the original task is written as follows:

```
abstract class OriginalTask : DefaultTask() {
    
    @get:OutputFile
    abstract val outputFile: RegularFileProperty

    @TaskAction
    fun createFile() {
        outputFile.get().asFile.writeText("Werther's original")
    }
    
}
```

Then, running `./gradlew originalDependant` will output `Found contents: Werther's original` to the console. `createOriginalFileTask` has created the file, and `originalDependant` has printed out its contents.

###### Modified setup

Now we carry out the plan to insert a task between these two. We write a task class as below. I have added comments where the key steps take place:

```
abstract class ModifyingTask : DefaultTask() {

    @get:InputFile
    abstract val unmovableFileProperty: RegularFileProperty

    /**
     * Step 1, we use a separate pseudo output directory to give Gradle a place to reference for
     * caching of this task
     */
    @get:OutputDirectory
    abstract val pseudoOutputDirectoryProperty: DirectoryProperty

    @get:OutputFile
    abstract val pseudoOutputFile: RegularFileProperty

    fun linkOutputFile() {
        pseudoOutputFile.set(pseudoOutputDirectoryProperty.flatMap { dir -> dir.file(unmovableFileProperty.map { it.asFile.name }) } )
    }

    @TaskAction
    fun modifyAndWriteToPseudoLocation() {
        val inputFile = unmovableFileProperty.get().asFile
        pseudoOutputFile.get().asFile
            .writeText(inputFile.readText() + " You know when you've been tangoed")
        println("Modified original file")
    }

}
```

And we add the following to the `build.gradle.kts`, continuing our `tasks` configuration and linking all properties together to establish task dependency relationships:

```
tasks {
    // Continued from above build.gradle.kts
    val modifyingTask = register<ModifyingTask>("modify") {
        unmovableFileProperty.value(createOriginalFileTask.flatMap { it.outputFile })
        pseudoOutputDirectoryProperty.set(layout.buildDirectory.dir("pseudoOutput"))
        linkOutputFile()
        doLast {
            /**
             * Step 2, silently copying the files back. Note this is done as a
             * "project.copy" and not a fully fledged task of its own as Gradle will
             * try and add such a task into its dependency and caching systems
             * (which we do not want)
             */
            project.copy {
                from(pseudoOutputFile)
                into(unmovableFileProperty.get().asFile.parentFile)
            }
        }
    }
    /**
     * Step 3, making our modification task run after the original task to preserve
     * existing task dependency chains.
     */
    createOriginalFileTask.configure {
        finalizedBy(modifyingTask)
    }
}
```

Run this new build with `./gradlew originalDependant` and the output will read:

```
Modified original file
Found contents: Werther's original You know when you've been tangoed
```

Run it one more time and it will output:

```
Found contents: Werther's original You know when you've been tangoed
```

The modification task does not run on this second invocation, showing that it has been successfully cached.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed answer which definitely solves the problem for me. However, it solves the problem in a bit of a complicated way and I feel that Gradle should provide direct support for this kind of feature. In essence, Gradle build cache is "just" a memoization problem: if this is input -> this will be output and I can remember the output. There's no fundamental reason memoization would not work for files that are both inputs and outputs. I'll accept your solution and I'll also open a feature request at Gradle GitHub to add proper support for this kind of situation.

Comment: Gradle does provide memoization for files that are both inputs and outputs—just that multiple tasks cannot share the same output (and will error if you do so, as you've probably discovered). I think it's trying to be helpful by preventing this as it looks like an error as you wouldn't design your build this way if you had control over every aspect. But that's not the world we live in so, yes, I agree it would be helpful if there was a way to override that rule simply.

Comment: Also, another issue with the above answer is that if `ModifyingTask` needs to be re-run (ie one of its inputs changes) but `OriginalTask` doesn't, Gradle will not re-run it if you are invoking some task downstream of both when you run your build. I haven't found a satisfactory solution for that yet. So another reason it would be great if Gradle anticipated this problem.