# In Gradle, automatically create dependency for my task

Tags: android, gradle

In Gradle, there is a built in task called `JavaWithJavac`. I wrote my own task `ScalaWithScalac`, which also outputs in the same directory with output of `JavaWithJavac`. `ScalaWithScalac` depends on the task `JavaWithJavac`. In my project, I need to import Android Gradle Plugin. Bunch of tasks in Android Gradle Plugin, for example, task `dexBuilder`, depends on `JavaWithJavac` and access to the output directory of `JavaWithJavac`. So the Gradle system makes error that these tasks must explicitly depends on `ScalaWithScalac` because `ScalaWithScalac` outputs the same directory with `JavaWithJavac`. The error message looks like this:

```
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':dexBuilderDebug' (type 'DexArchiveBuilderTask').
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\java\workspace\project\build\intermediates\javac\Debug\classes'.
    
    Reason: Task ':dexBuilderDebug' uses this output of task ':compileDebugScalaWithScalac' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed.
    
    Possible solutions:
      1. Declare task ':compileDebugScalaWithScalac' as an input of ':dexBuilderDebug'.
      2. Declare an explicit dependency on ':compileDebugScalaWithScalac' from ':dexBuilderDebug' using Task#dependsOn.
      3. Declare an explicit dependency on ':compileDebugScalaWithScalac' from ':dexBuilderDebug' using Task#mustRunAfter.
    
    For more information, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.5/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency in the Gradle documentation.
```

So I added explicit dependency for them.

```
dexBuilder dependsOn scalaWithScalac
javaRes dependsOn scalaWithScalac
// configuration goes on for every tasks depends on JavaWithJavac
```

The problem is that Android Gradle Plugin changes often, so many new tasks are depends on `JavaWithJavac`, and I need to repeatedly checks them and add explicit dependency to `ScalaWithScalac`. That's not a good way to solve the problem.

I want to extend the task `JavaWithJavac`, so that it runs the `ScalaWithScalac` task as its last step, so any other task depends on `JavaWithJavac` automatically depends on `ScalaWithScalac`. But the task `JavaWithJavac` is provided with Gradle, and don't know how to extend the existing task that I cannot change its source code. How do I do?

I tried `javaWithJavac finalizedby scalaWithScalac` but this does not make `dexBuilder` to depends on `scalaWithScalac` automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem in Gradle ([Github issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/27696)): where you are looking to modify the output files of a task (here your `JavaWithJavac`) and not change the output location. The ideal Gradle solution is to have a separate output location, but it can be impracticable to get all the downstream tasks of the original task (here `JavaWithJavac`) to use the new output location.

The work-around is to have your additional task (`ScalaWithScalac`):

1. Declare its output directory as an entirely separate directory, and
2. 'Silently' copy the resulting files to the 'correct JavaWithJavac` output directory.

Then Gradle has a separate output directory to look at for `ScalaWithScalac` and it will not complain that unlinked downstream tasks are using that output.

To silently copy (ie do so without declaring the output directory as an output), you can add the final action to `ScalaWithScalac` (using Kotlin DSL here):

```
tasks.named("ScalaWithScalac") {
    doLast {
        copy {
            from(outputDirectory) // Or whatever it is labelled as
            into(
                named<TypeOfJavaWithJavaC>("javaWithJavaC").map {
                    it.outputDirectory // Or whatever it is labelled as within TypeOfJavaWithJavaC (not its real name!)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The full work-around is also covered in [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77807234/gradle-cache-task-which-processes-a-file-in-place).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the @Simon Jacobs answer, I managed to avoid Gradle error without explicitly declaring dependencies.
To be clear, I wrote a more concise toy example to demonstrate this problem and workaround.

```
val taskX by tasks.registering(Copy::class) {
    from(file("taskXin"))
    into(file("taskXout"))
    doLast {
        println("taskX finished")
    }
}
val taskY by tasks.registering(Copy::class) {
    from(file("taskYin"))
    into(taskX.get().destinationDir)
    doLast {
        println("taskY finished")
    }
}
taskX { finalizedBy(taskY) }

val taskZ by tasks.registering(Copy::class) {
    from(taskX.get().destinationDir)
    into(file("taskZout"))
    doLast {
        println("taskZ finished")
    }
}
taskZ { dependsOn(taskX) }
```

This produces 'Gradle detected a problem with the following location:' error, but changing `taskY` as shown below does not:

```
val taskY by tasks.registering(Copy::class) {
    from(file("taskYin"))
    into("taskYout")
    doLast {
        copy {
            from("taskYout")
            into(taskX.get().destinationDir)
        }

        println("taskY finished")
    }
}
```

Gradle originally warned about the build could lead to incorrect results, but this change effectively turned it off without following Gradle's dictation. As far as I tested with this toy example, build outcome meets my expectation. But still I don't know whether this workaround always produces correct output or not.